# Generate set of Ids from a map, am I doing it right?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to generate a set of Opportunity Ids that have 'Legal' cases. But I'm getting the 'inner select field 'Opportunity__r.Id' cannot have more than one level of relationships. 
Is there a better way of doing this without first pulling a list of sObjects then iterating using a for loop to get the Ids?
Thank for helping out!

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE     Id IN (SELECT Opportunity__r.Id FROM Case WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Legal')]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `__r.Id` to `__c`. That way it does not resolve to an object but just an Id.

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
    SELECT Id FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT Opportunity__c
        FROM Case
        WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Legal'
    )
]).keySet().clone();
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Tried it but I'm getting an 'Illegal assignment' error from Map to Set.

Comment: You should also tweak the query to use `RecordType.DeveloperName`, which is unique.